# Why or When is between-group variance equal to the covariance among members of a group?

Tags: variance, covariance, biostatistics, genetics

In Introduction to Quantitative Genetics (Falconer) , one of the ways of estimating heritability of a trait is by using a full-sib/half-sib model. In a full-sib/half-sib model, a number of males are each mated to to or more females to produce offspring. Heritability is estimated by comparing the covariances and variances of the trait within and between groups of offspring. It is stated that "any between-group variance is equal to the covariance of the members of the groups", which I was not able to understand. It seems like a general statement from the book, and is applied both to groups of offspring that share a single male parent, and to groups of offspring that do not share any parents. Can anyone direct me to any resources that explain this? Thank you!